# append a string in output section

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

This output works as expected.
It shows the URL of the instance.

```
Outputs:
  thisInstance:
    Value: !GetAtt [MySpotInstance, PublicDnsName]
    Description: Jupyter Notebook on port 8888
```

But this does not work.
I am trying to add ":8888" to the URL created as above.

```
Outputs:
  thisInstance:
    Value: !Sub ${!GetAtt [MySpotInstance, PublicDnsName]}:8888
    Description: Jupyter Notebook on port 8888
```

I just need to append ":8888" to the string and show it in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need:

```yaml
Outputs:
  thisInstance:
    Value: !Sub 
       - '${dns}:8888'
       - dns: !GetAtt [MySpotInstance, PublicDnsName]
    Description: Jupyter Notebook on port 8888
```